# How does this code that prints 1 to 1000 work in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I've seen a C program that prints 1 to 1000 without using any looping structure or conditional statements, but I don't understand how it works. Can anyone go through the code and explain each line?
See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/sHrI3L). Why does it result in a runtime error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    ((void(*[])()){main, exit})[i / 1000](i + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One line, because recursive `main()` is not prohibited in C.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Is it explicitly said by C standard? Better If you come up with Standard citation.

Comment: No, completely absent. There comes the hack.

Comment: before asking for standard citation, may I ask which part did you actually try to read, and maybe did not understand?

Comment: Recursion is just another word for "fancy loop".

Comment: @Downvoters: what's wrong in question. specify reason for downvotes.

Comment: Whereas the C standard does not explicitly say that you may call `main()` recursively, some of its wording does anticipate the possibility.  For instance, "a return from the *initial* call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument" (C2011 5.1.2.2.3; emphasis added).

Comment: because `exit(1000+1)`  ideone understand run time error that  return value is not zero  http://ideone.com/rU4dCo

Comment: Function pointer casts are not standard C. Unless the compiler has a non-standard extension, they will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: On the other hand the standard does flatly say "Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain
of other functions" (C2011 6.5.2.2/11).  Although it doesn't name `main()` as included, neither does it make an exception for `main()`.  In the absence of an explicit exception, I see no reason to suppose that the standard permits one.

Comment: Note that this definition of `main` is not standard; `main` either takes 0 parameters or 2 parameters (`int` and `char **`).  So while this code may compile and run, it's invoking undefined behavior all over the place.

Comment: `int i` used as main arg is worng: `error: ‘main’ takes only zero or two arguments|`. 2) You have also `initialization from incompatible pointer type` in `((void(*[])()){main, exit})` you should use a proper compiler and turn on your warnings.

Comment: "*To understand recursion, you need to understand recursion, you need to ...*" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((void(*[])()){main, exit})[i / 1000](i + 1);
```

This line create a two-element array of function pointers, with the first element containing the `main` function, and other element containing the `exit` function.

It then indexes this array by `i / 1000`. This either gets the `main` function if `i < 1000` or the `exit` function when `i == 1000`.

It then calls the function pointer that it just indexed with `i+1` as the argument.

It's a recursive function, with the stopping condition determined with an array index rather than a conditional. I don't think it's valid C however; `main`'s signature is wrong, and the cast to a function pointer removes the return type from the `main` function.

Comment: @PravasiMeet NO, is just wrong. That's all. Never code like that.

Answer (score 4):

Breaking down the line that you asked about

```
((void(*[])()){main, exit})
```

This is an array literal, which creates an unnamed temp array of two function pointers, and initializes those pointers to point at `main` and `exit`

```
[i / 1000]
```

This indexes that temp array.  Integer division truncates towards 0, so when 0 <= i < 1000, this gets element 0 (the pointer to `main`) and when 1000 <= i < 1999, it gets element 1 (the pointer to `exit`)

```
(i + 1);
```

This calls the pointed at function with i+1 as an argument.

There are a bunch of things here that are undefined behavior.  Declaring `main` as having a single int argument is illegal according to the standard, though generally will work, getting the number of command line arguments as the single argument.  Getting a pointer to `main` is likewise undefined, as `main` is a special function that may have a non-standard calling convention.

Comment: It is not illegal to declare `main()` as having a single `int` argument.  It probably does produce undefined behavior, but the standard permits implementations to define behavior for this or other signatures of `main()`.  Indeed, it is common for Unix implementations to recognize and define behavior for a three-argument form, where the program's environment strings are provided via the third argument.  I don't know any implementation that supports a one-arg form, though.

Comment: The spec (5.1.2.2.1) states that main "shall be defined" with no arguments or two (int and char **) -- any program that violates a "shall be" requirement is undefined by the spec.  Of course, any implementation may define any behavior for any undefined construct as an extension and still be in compliance with the spec, as no diagnostic is required for undefined behavior.

Comment: You didn't read far enough: "[...] or in some other implementation-defined manner." (C2011 5.1.2.2.1/1)  Thus, as long as the implementation defines a given signature for `main()`, use of that signature with that implementation does not inherently yield undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This code is a good example of how far you can bend C without breaking it. You shouldn't attempt to understand this until you can write *understandable* C.

Here are the key features and assumptions:

First, assume that the program is called without arguments. The parameter `i` is in the place usually called `argc`, so it will have the initial value 1 (the number of elements in the array of arguments, usually called `argv`).

Next, assume that the single-argument form of `main` doesn't cause any problems. Officially supported forms of `main` are with no arguments, 2 arguments (`argc, argv`), and sometimes 3 arguments (`argc, argv, envp`).

So the first `printf` prints 1.

Next we have a compound literal. It might be easier to understand if you look at a simpler one first:

```
(int[]){10,20}
```

That's an anonymous array of 2 `int`s, with values 10 and 20. `int[]` is the type. It goes in parentheses before a braced list of values. So what's this:

```
(void(*[])()){main, exit}
```

`void(*[])()` is a type. It means array of function pointers with the signature `void (*foo)()`. The type name in parentheses followed by a braced list is compound literal, just like the `(int[]){10,20}` example. In this case, it creates an array of 2 function pointers whose elements are `main` and `exit`.

Assume that the mismatch between the function pointer type (returns `void`) and `main` (returns `int`) doesn't cause a problem.

This:

```
((void(*[])()){main, exit})[i / 1000]
```

is our anonymous array of 2 elements, inside some redundant parentheses, followed by `[i / 1000]`. That's just normal array indexing syntax. If `i/1000` is 0, you get the first element of the array (`thearray[0]`), which is `main`. That happens for all `i` is between 0 and 999. If `i/1000` is 1, which happens when `i==1000`, we're looking at `thearray[1]`, which gets us the second element: `exit`.

So far, we have an expression taht is equal to `main` when `i<1000` and equal to `exit` when `i==1000`.

Now look at the whole statement:

```
...that_big_thing_that_is_either_main_or_exit...(i + 1)
```

A function pointer, followed by a parenthesized argument list. That's a function call. Whichever function we chose from the array, now we're going to call it, providing an argument that is equal to the incoming argument (`i`) plus 1.

So the first call, when `i` is 1, selects `main` for the function and `i+1` = `1+1` = 2 for the argument. It calls `main(2)`.

`main(2)` does a `printf` which prints the 2, and then calls `main(3)`.

`main(3)` does a `printf` which prints the 3, and then calls `main(4)`.

...and so on until...

`main(999)` does a `printf` which prints the 999, and then calls `main(1000)`.

`main(1000)` does a `printf` which prints the 1000, and then calls `exit(1001)`.

None of the calls to `main` ever return, and the `return 0` never happens, because the `exit` terminates the process. The fact that the process returns an exit code of 1001 rather than 0 appears to be the reason for ideone's "runtime error" message.

Comment: `Ideone` should be used only after you compiled your code with a proper compiler to share your code. `Ideone` is also 32BIT compiler. Any way calling main recursive the stack will be consumed

Answer (score 0):

The `main function` is called recursively.

```
void print_nb(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1000)
    {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        print_nb(n + 1);
    }
}
```

Like  Sourav Ghosh said, it's prohibited to use with `main()` recursively, better use another function.

Comment: It is not prohibited, but calling main Recursive with exit code 0 (return 0) will eat all the stack. By the way @Sourav Ghosh said: One line, because recursive main() `is not prohibited in C`